# vb.net sql server query , can't see all result in dataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem when make a simple query in my database. 
I put the query results in lists of String and then I show the list in a dataGridView.
My DB is something like this

```
Time  |  Operations
......|...............
......|...............
......|...............
```

In operations column I have strings very long (about 24000 characters).
My code is

```
Public time= New List(Of String)
Public operations= New List(Of String)

query = "SELECT time, operations FROM TABLE1"

    Try
        SQLCon.Open()

        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(query, SQLCon)

        SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
        SQLDataset = New DataSet()
        SQLDA.Fill(SQLDataset)

        'READ DIRECTLY FROM DATABASE
        Dim R As SqlDataReader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

        While R.Read
            time.add(R(0).ToString)
            operations.add(R(1).ToString)
        End While

        SQLCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

        If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            SQLCon.Close()
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

To display in dataGridView I've used:

```
  For i = 0 To operations.count - 1
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(time(i), operations(i))
    Next
```

When I display in dataGridView, some items in operations column is blank.
Example

```
Time  |  Operations
11 feb|operations1=2................
11 feb|operations1=7................
12 jan|operations1=5................
13 jan|
14 jan|operations1=5................
20 jan|operations1=5................
```

If I try to show the related item, operations(index), in Msgbox I can see the value but in datagridview I can't.
Can you help me please? Thank you

Comment: you should read about databinding directly to the datagridview control, rather than explicitly adding each row one at a time. Also putting your results into two separate lists doesn't make a lot of sense, because you're basically splitting one meaningful result set into two unrelated objects...

Comment: ...You could use the DataTable object provided already by .NET and then bind that directly to the datagridivew - it will then create the columns automatically for you as well. That might end up solving your issue. Otherwise, there seems no obvious reason for the missing data, apart from maybe there isn't any ops data in the database for that date. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx for examples of databinding

Comment: Are you sure the `13 Jan` row has data there?  I agree a datatable would be much simpler.

Comment: I've read about databinding but also by following instructions the result doesn't change.
13 jan is just an example. The data is in the right format.
I did another test, if I use

SELECT SUBSTRING(operrations,1,23000) FROM TABLE1

it works.